# cordova facebook login does not respond on actual device

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I've integrated Facebook login in my ionic cordova app. The login works fine on my PC and android emulator.

But, when I install the app on the device (built using Intel XDK), the login button does not respond on click.

I've used the following :-
https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

My Controllers :-

```
myAppControllers.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal,       $timeout, ngFB, $location) {
$scope.fbLogin = function () {
ngFB.login({scope: 'email,publish_actions'}).then(
  function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log('Facebook login succeeded');
      $location.path( '/profile' );
      $scope.closeLogin();
    } else {
      alert('Facebook login failed');
    }
  });
};
});
```

Controller to display the user detail :-

```
myAppControllers.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ngFB) {
ngFB.api({
path: '/me',
params: {fields: 'id,name,email,gender,location'}
}).then(
function (user) {
  $scope.user = user;
},
function (error) {
  alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
});
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install an ng-cordova plugin i.e.,$cordovaInAppBrowser to get your facebook login up and running in your android mobile device..Just type the below command in your terminal from your project's root folder.And then run the application in your mobile device.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Answer (score 0):

Which device/OS are you using?  Which facebook plugin?  In either case, go to the debug tab and build your debuggable version of the app for testing.  You will get access to Chrome Developer Tools and will be able to see if there are any errors happening.

Comment: I am using Moto E and Intel XDK to build. I tested the app on intel XDK, and the only error it gave me was - "cannot read property keyboard ofundefined"

Comment: Is that on device or in the emulator?  It looks like it's expecting the Ionic Keyboard plugin, but it was not added to your project.  I do know there was a bug with plugins that should be fixed in the hotfix that was just released.

Comment: the error is in emulator. Also, I updated the file config.xml by adding - <allow-navigation href="*" /> and added Content Security Policy meta tag in the index file. Now facebook login works in intel xdk emulator, but why is it not working on actual device, i don't understand...

Comment: Ok - the emulator does not emulate cordova plugins.  On device, you will need to do debugging to get actual errors, otherwise I can't help much.